# Match some words between two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to match some words between two columns. I am not able to find this solution anywhere, so i need help.

```
|==========title=================|======title================|
|...Toscano Brioche..............|...Toscano .... ...........|
|....Toscano Brioche Creme.......|...Brioche Creme Butter....|
```

OUTPUT==>

```
|==========title=================|======title================|===OUTPUT===|
|...Toscano Brioche..............|...Toscano .... ...........|   1        |
|....Toscano Brioche Creme.......|...Brioche Creme Butter....|   1        |
|....Strawberry CAKE Bakery......|...Brioche Creme Butter....|   0        |
```

How to compare these two columns named 'title' in table, I need to match some words between the two columns. For example, in row 1, 'Toscano' is common in both columns, in row 2,  'Brioche Creme' is common.

Comment: You have two columns with the same name. I'm already confused.

Comment: Can you plz add the desired output.

Comment: Are you trying to `INNER JOIN` on text here?

Comment: @AnkitBajpai Output can be 1 or 0. is it possible in sql? I need to do in sql only

Comment: @PaulAldred-Bann: No, I just need to match common words. No inner join. If common match is found then return true or false

Comment: Do you want to check if one string in contained in the other ? Or you want to calculate the distance between two strings ? First case you can use MySQL functions, second case write a function that implements Levenshtein distance

Comment: @Kabulan0lak: I want to check if one string is contained in the other. I can't use php, i have to do this in mysql only. I didn't find answer from mysql functions.

Comment: You just have to use LIKE. You want a boolean for every single row int your result ?

Comment: @AmukSaxena Are the `title` columns in two different tables?

Comment: I think what Amuk looking at should be list down the keyword that appear in both column, if resultset cannot be the keyword, true/false is enough for him. 
1 question, @AmukSaxena, you want to compare line by line ? or line 1 on left need to scan through whole table ?

Comment: @JosephB: No same table.

Comment: @Kabulan0lak: How can we use LIKE ?

Comment: @ah_hau: If there is a sentence: "Hello how are you" in column one, and in column two "Hello world how are you". Then it should tell me that the string contains some common elements between the two columns

Comment: Something like `(title1 LIKE %title2%) OR (title2 LIKE %title1%)`

Comment: Edit you question and add expected result because you're really not clear

Comment: @Kabulan0lak: I tried it, but it will return false in some conditions. If the two columns contain same strings it will return always true. Column1==> "Hello World" . Columns2==> "Hello World" . In this situation i will implement LIKE query. But what if Column1==> "Hello how are you" Column2==>"Hello world how are you"

Comment: @AmukSaxena in that case, what you're after (as others have said) is `LIKE` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like

Comment: You want to extract common words from two strings ? Or just check if there is any common words between two string ?

Comment: @Kabulan0lak: Edited question. Want to check common words between two strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this (SQL FIDDLE [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/388467/4)) ?

```
SELECT table1.title title1, table2.title title2
FROM table1, table2
WHERE table1.title LIKE CONCAT('%',table2.title,'%') 
OR table2.title LIKE CONCAT('%',table1.title,'%');
```

Answer (score 2):

Not able to understand your question completely, I think you want to compare 2 columns, if those have some common words then show 1. May be it can help you..

```
select title1,title2,title1 like concat("%",replace(title2," ","%"),"%") as matched from table_name
```

**EDIT:** You can see accepted answer if these two columns are from different table. By the way that is obvious. But don't forgot to use replace as I did if you want to find all words anywhere.