# Get data matches between two tables - if at least three characters matches or more

Tags: sql, sql-server

how can I get data matches between two tables, the logic of matching should be - if at least three characters matches or more:

In one table I have:

```
Assets
--------
MADFG
NGGS_Data
KTL_GAS_LCN
FI
```

in another table:

```
Asset
------------
VERT
NGS
KTLGAS
FIP
```

as Output I need:

```
Asset_table1    Asset_table2
-----------     ------------
NGGS_Data       NGS
KTL_GAS_LCN     KTLGAS
```

I was trying to use query from this example [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25055254/match-some-words-between-two-columns) but this doesn't give me result I need:

thanks,
S

Comment: SQL is a programming language.  You need to express `rules` about how two rows relate to each other.  What are the rules you want to express in SQL?  Should an asset `'G'` match three of the assets in your first table?  Should matching ignore all non alphabetic characters?  Should matching always be from the start of the strings, or could matching happen in the middle of strings?  What is the longest string allowed?  Do the three matching characters have to be in the same order in both strings?  Does it need to be case sensitive? *(You need to be explicit and specific.)*

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying all things,  all non alphabetic characters should be ignored and at least two characters should be in the same order in both tables, doesn't need to be case sensitive.

Comment: Why doesn't "FI" match "FIP"?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to use a recursive CTE. This gives the desired results.

```
CREATE TABLE #Assets(Assets VARCHAR(20))
CREATE TABLE #Asset(Asset VARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO #Assets VALUES
('MADFG')
,('NGGS_Data')
,('KTL_GAS_LCN')
,('FI')

INSERT INTO #Asset VALUES
('VERT')
,('NGS')
,('KTLGAS')
,('FIP')

;WITH cteAssets AS
(
    SELECT
        Assets
        ,left(Assets,2) Char2
        ,RIGHT(Assets,len(assets)-1) Rem
    FROM
        #Assets
    WHERE len(Assets) >= 3
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        Assets
        ,left(Rem,2) Char2
        ,RIGHT(Rem,len(Rem)-1) Rem
    FROM
        cteAssets
    WHERE len(Rem) >= 2
)
SELECT DISTINCT
    A.Assets
    ,B.Asset
FROM
    cteAssets A
        INNER JOIN #Asset B
            ON
            CHARINDEX(A.Char2,B.Asset,0) > 0
```