# How to show only rows where there is no match between strings at all?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string-matching

I have to compare two columns and be able to extract only rows where there is not even a partial match between strings. For example, I have this table:

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| John Smith | John Smith ltd |
| Pepper Row | Whatever Pepper |
| red | Blue |

The only row I should be seeing after the filtration is the last one:

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| red | Blue |

I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25055254/match-some-words-between-two-columns) which shows results with partial matches. I tried to modify it to return only 0 matches by using `NOT LIKE` but it did not work out.

Comment: `'Blue`' and '`Red`' both have the letter `'e'`, why isn't that a "match"? What counts as matching and what doesn't? What if one was `'John Smith ltd'` and the other `'Jane Grey Limited'` Would you expect `'ltd'` and `'Limited'` to match?

Comment: A match is a whole word, not a single letter. I don't expect ltd. and Limited to match.

Comment: And an abbreviation of a word doesn't count as a match? Can you have punctuation in there such as a `.` or `,`? What about something like `'Jane Smith's` and `'John Smith'`? They are both `'Smith'`.

Comment: Well, the link that I provided will show me rows such as your example and I will see that these are different companies. and will assess what to do. But in my case I have either similarity like this `'John Smith'`, `'John Smith Ltd'`, or there is total difference like: `'Apple inc'`, `'Pear ltd'`. I want to show the latter, because in my case it will indicate where the updates did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want rows where none of the words overlap, you can use a `not exists` clause:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from string_split(t.col1, ' ') s1 join
                       string_split(t.col2, ' ') s2
                       on s1.value = s2.value
                 );
```

Note:  This formulation allows you to return the entire row -- that is, other columns that are not included in the comparison.

If you are using an older version of SQL Server that does not support `string_split()`, I would suggest finding the code for a user-defined function that does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to split col1 words and want to check if it is present in the col2 or not, for this you can try like following.

```
select col1,col2 from mytable
except   
select col1,col2 from mytable t
cross apply
(
 select * from string_split(t.Col1,' ')
)x    
where col2  like  '%' + [value] + '%'
```

**Note**: `string_split` will work on SQL Server 2017+, if you are using older version you need to use some custom split function.